# Life Cycle of Mule Event

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

Hi i have started working with Mule Anypoint Studio and would like to know what are the different stages of a basic Mule Event. Like how does mule start and stop a particular event in a flow. Also how a flow gets initialised.

Answer (score 2):

The mule event can not be compare as a "life cycle" bean as the behaviour is completely different.

A Mule Event is created when a message source is trigger by any action , this action outputs a message.  The event contain this message inside.

When the event pass through a different number of processors, you just modify the data in that message.

If the transport you are using is based on request-response transport, the same event continues in the same thread.

Is it possible to create new events / copy the event into another one (scatter-gather), etc..

But there is nothing like lifecycle in a MuleEvent , event is created, processed and it ends when the process is completed.

Comment: I was wondering will there be some initialisation of some objects or some methods will be called when a mule flow comes into action?

Comment: hei charle,  you can always have a look in the mulesoft apidocs

https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.8.3/apidocs/

for instance,  have a look in FlowConstruct, Flow and other Flow notification elements  in the API to solve any questions.

On the other hand, this is going offtopic from your original Mule Event questions.

If the original question was solved, could you please rate the answer as a valid question?  If you have more questions after having a look in api doc, please submit a new question in the forum.